# Exposed proximity filter in geofield required, but still gives result

Tags: views, location

I've made a view with geofield proximity search. The user needs to fill in a location before I want to show result. So I made the exposed filter required: 
[image: geofield proximity settings]

But the view gives result, even when nothing is filled in. This is the query created:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.language AS node_language, 'node' AS field_data_field_adres_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_location_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_location} field_data_field_location ON node.nid = field_data_field_location.entity_id AND (field_data_field_location.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_location.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('dealer')) ))
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
```

How can I make sure the query doesn't run if nothing is filled in?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are using [Better exposed filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module and configured as this image. [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't test it at this time because there is a (very small) workaround in place. If anyone else can confirm, I'll gladly accept the answer.